# How do I set up a formula that will return a certain value dependent upon a portion of text in a cell?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I've got a column of text.  If the text of the cell contains

**el**

I want it to return **"M"** in the adjacent column.  If the cell contains

**la**

instead, I want it to return **"F"** in the adjacent column.

Below is an image of what I mean, but what you see has been done manually.

[image]

From the beginning I thought there might be a formula that could do this, but thought it might be faster to just do it manually.  In fact, this may, indeed, be true, but should I need to do something like this again in the future, an answer that I might get from the superuser StackExchange just might save me some time.  Plus, it might help others who are attempting to do something similar.

What is the easiest way to do this?  I am using Excel 2007.

Also, if this has already been answered in another thread, forgive me for adding this here.  I have glanced and even opened some of the ones that seem to touch on this topic, but none are exactly matching what it is I am attempting to do.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions, guidance, and expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest two IF statments:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" el ",A1)),"M",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" la ",A1)),"F",""))
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, my answer was going to check for "la" first, but this will suffice!  I was too slow, probably from manually typing all the samples :)

Comment: Haven't tried it out yet @Scott Craner, but I am super impressed with how quickly you answered this.  I can't wait to see if this works.  Your rep of 1,443 gives me a very good feeling.  I'll check it out now and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @fixer1234 you are of course correct.  Fixed.

Comment: @Scott Craner  First of all, sorry for the delayed response.  I got sidetracked onto a completely different project of sorts.  Despite that, I eventually got back to this and because your suggested formula worked perfectly, I have to conclude that you are, quite simply, amazing.  How did you get so good with Excel formulas?